# sbt-native-packager RPM issue

Tags: playframework, sbt, rpm, sbt-native-packager

We use sbt to build our backend, which based on Play framework.
Currently we use sbt dist and run a build binary file.

I am working with building it to RPM package, and some error raises during this process.

I found this repo - https://github.com/muuki88/sbt-native-packager-examples
ran a

```
sbt clean rpm:package-bin
```

under both rpm related subdirs - `rpm-sigar` and `simple-rpm`, the same errors were raised, like in my project, please see traceback:

```
oreststetsiak@spyro ~/coding/sbt-native-packager-examples/simple-rpm $ sbt clean rpm:package-bin
[info] Loading project definition from /home/oreststetsiak/coding/sbt-native-packager-examples/simple-rpm/project
[info] Set current project to simple-rpm (in build file:/home/oreststetsiak/coding/sbt-native-packager-examples/simple-rpm/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Aug 23, 2016 6:54:33 PM
[info] Packaging /home/oreststetsiak/coding/sbt-native-packager-examples/simple-rpm/target/scala-2.10/simple-rpm_2.10-1.0-sources.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Updating {file:/home/oreststetsiak/coding/sbt-native-packager-examples/simple-rpm/}simple-rpm...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Main Scala API documentation to /home/oreststetsiak/coding/sbt-native-packager-examples/simple-rpm/target/scala-2.10/api...
[info] Wrote /home/oreststetsiak/coding/sbt-native-packager-examples/simple-rpm/target/scala-2.10/simple-rpm_2.10-1.0.pom
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/oreststetsiak/coding/sbt-native-packager-examples/simple-rpm/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[warn] there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
model contains 4 documentable templates
[warn] one warning found
[info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
[info] Packaging /home/oreststetsiak/coding/sbt-native-packager-examples/simple-rpm/target/scala-2.10/simple-rpm_2.10-1.0-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[warn] there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
[warn] one warning found
[info] Packaging /home/oreststetsiak/coding/sbt-native-packager-examples/simple-rpm/target/scala-2.10/simple-rpm_2.10-1.0.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[error] + umask 022
[error] + cd /home/oreststetsiak/coding/sbt-native-packager-examples/simple-rpm/target/rpm/BUILD
[error] + [ -e /home/oreststetsiak/coding/sbt-native-packager-examples/simple-rpm/target/rpm/buildroot ]
[error] + mv /home/oreststetsiak/coding/sbt-native-packager-examples/simple-rpm/target/rpm/tmp-buildroot/etc /home/oreststetsiak/coding/sbt-native-packager-examples/simple-rpm/target/rpm/tmp-buildroot/usr /home/oreststetsiak/coding/sbt-native-packager-examples/simple-rpm/target/rpm/tmp-buildroot/var /home/oreststetsiak/coding/sbt-native-packager-examples/simple-rpm/target/rpm/buildroot
[error] + /usr/lib/rpm/brp-compress
[error] + /usr/lib/rpm/brp-strip /usr/bin/strip
[info] Building target platforms: noarch-mukis.de-Linux
[info] Building for target noarch-mukis.de-Linux
[info] Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /tmp/sbt_53b70991/rpm-tmp.yZCzUZ
[error] + /usr/lib/rpm/brp-strip-static-archive /usr/bin/strip
[error] + /usr/lib/rpm/brp-strip-comment-note /usr/bin/strip /usr/bin/objdump
[info] Processing files: simple-rpm-1.0-1.noarch
[info] Provides: config(simple-rpm) = 1.0-1 simple-rpm = 1.0-1
[info] Requires(interp): /bin/sh /bin/sh /bin/sh /bin/sh
[info] Requires(rpmlib): rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1 rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
[info] Requires(pre): /bin/sh
[info] Requires(post): /bin/sh
[info] Requires(preun): /bin/sh
[info] Requires(postun): /bin/sh
[info] Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /home/oreststetsiak/coding/sbt-native-packager-examples/simple-rpm/target/rpm/buildroot
[info] Wrote: /home/oreststetsiak/coding/sbt-native-packager-examples/simple-rpm/target/rpm/RPMS/noarch/simple-rpm-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
[info] Executing(%clean): /bin/sh -e /tmp/sbt_53b70991/rpm-tmp.e0IrHo
[error] + umask 022
[error] + cd /home/oreststetsiak/coding/sbt-native-packager-examples/simple-rpm/target/rpm/BUILD
[error] + /bin/rm -rf /home/oreststetsiak/coding/sbt-native-packager-examples/simple-rpm/target/rpm/buildroot
[error] + exit 0
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed Aug 23, 2016 6:54:36 PM
```

My workstation is Linux Mint 18 based, which is DEB.

Also I tried to build it under RedHat 7.2 in AWS EC2 - the same error,

This kind of errors does not break builds in Jenkins CI, but I would like not see it in the build log.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You are not experiencing an error. As you can see in the last line

```
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed Aug 23, 2016 6:54:36 PM
```

The result was a success. RPM unfortunately logs to stderr.

Comment: that is good, thanx, and one more quest: we use a lot of env varieblas, and service works good, just in case, if I manually add all thesee env variebles in startup script, is this a good approach? how/where do you reccommend to keep bunch of sensetive env variables? Regards! appreciate your help ....

Comment: From my experience sensitive env variables should not be part of your start script, neither should they be checked into your repo. A good example is the play application secret. They should be provided by the system you are running your service on (this is why they are called environment variables after all ;) ). Talk to your ops folks for this :)

Comment: does "They should be provided by the system you are running your service on" means that all env variables should be a global environment variables, available with command **env** ? in fact we have **play application secret** in a list of env varialbes, piece of other env variables (like S3 user, DB url, DB username/password etc) is creating during provisioning AWS Cloud formation Template